# wget 443 connection error

Tags: networking, vim

I'm using bash on Ubuntu. I'm still pretty new to vim and bash, and I want to download some vim packages. I'm having a 443 connection error when trying to connect to github. I download the git-core `sudo apt-get install vim git-core wget`. I can connect to other sites. If I use `wget https://google.com` it will return `index.html`. I'm trying to get a vimrc file by inputting 
`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thesheff17/youtube/master/vim/vimrc`. This returns a 443 connection refused error. When connecting to google.com, it uses the 443 port, so the port should be fine. I am using wi-fi, but if port works for other sites then this shouldn't matter. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: I read about trying `export http_proxy='192.64.119.130:443` but this didn't help.

Comment: The command should work fine just as you have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to upload .vimrc. On Ubuntu it's

```
   ~/.vimrc
```

So do

```
 vi ~/.vimrc
```

Copy the default content from step 3 in https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim
and follow the instructions described there to upload Vundle plugin and using Vundle to install any Vim plugins. To exit vi type :wq (w to write, q to quit)

Comment: well I don't see a `.vimrc` file in my home directory. I see a `.vim` directory, and a `.viminfo` file. I will try vundle though

Comment: You generate it yourself. Run touch ~/.vimrc or just open it - if it does not exist it will be automatically created for you when you use vi or nano editor - vi ~/.vimrc

Comment: ok, I wasn't to sure of that. I created a `.vimrc` file and placed the info they suggested in the file.

Comment: So just follow the Vundle instructions -  vim +PluginInstall +qall in command line or :PluginInstall within vim

Comment: 2 of the plugins won't install. Thanks for the help. I'll have to do some more research.

Comment: You're welcome. Just take some time to see how vimrc syntax is structured and Vundle docs would be helpful too.